# Разрешение на чтение и запись файлов во внешнем пространстве

Tags: android, файлы, permissions

В приложении в AndroidManifest.xml прописано:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Однако при открытии приложения на Android 8.0.0 работа с файловой системой становится возможной только после установки настроек приложения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать возможность работу с внешней памятью автоматической, или во всяком случае спрашивать один раз при первом запуске приложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У себя в приложении для подобной задачи я использую функцию:

```
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}
```

очень действенное решение и меня всегда спасает. Нашел этот способ получения разрешения на английской части SO ([ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow)). Надеюсь вам поможет так же как и мне. Удачи :)

Comment: А где вызывать функцию isStoragePermissionGranted()?

Comment: ну где вам нужно? ну перед тем как делать что-то с хранилищем вы вызываете эту функцию и в зависимости от того что она вернула вы дальше либо работаете с файлами, либо просите разрешение у пользователя поработать с файлами.

Comment: а если в приложении масса случаев записи файлов, можно вызвать эту функцию один раз при открытии, и если будет true, то продолжить работу, или каждый раз нужно вызывать? и как FileOutputStream понимает, что пермишн получен?

Comment: да можно однократно вызвать, и дальше уже вы сможете работать с файлами без перебоев до момента пока не удалите приложение или отключите это разрешение. Поток записи файла понимает что разрешение получено очень просто -  либо пишет, либо нет))

Comment: большое спасибо!!! всё получилось)