# Доступ к чтению файлов из внутреннего хранилища

Tags: java, android, permissions

Имеется следующий код метода:

```
ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        @SuppressLint("Recycle")
        Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri,null,null,null,null);
        if (musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
            int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            do{
                long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                songsList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
            }while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

При выполнении выдает ошибку:

```
Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=2341, uid=10101 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

В манифесте строка     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` присутствует. В документации посмотрел статью про разрешения https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting
Понял, что это возникает из-за API, но не совсем понял, откуда берется `MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS`
во втором листинге и как вообще это применить к коду

**UPD**

Добавил метод:

```
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Почему-то в логах не нашел ничего с тэгом активности, но по дебаггеру, метод возвращает false. [image: Вот скрин]

В таком случае вопрос - как получить доступ к данным в данной ситуации?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927091/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5/927149#927149

Comment: Какая версия андроида? В последних версиях мало строки в манифесте, нужно 1) запросить разрешение у пользователя и 2) перед использованием каждый раз проверять наличие.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, обновил вопрос

Comment: Еще раз: **нужно 1) запросить разрешение у пользователя и 2) перед использованием каждый раз проверять наличие.** Ничего этого в коде нет.