# Запросить WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE при запуске программы

Tags: android-studio, permissions, realtime

У меня есть программа интернет магазин ,я хочу сделать запрос permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE при запуске программы после того как запустится Splash программы.Может кто знает как это можно реализовать приведите какой нибудь пример. 
Сейчас программа запускается.

```
public class ActivitySplash extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

затем MainActivity

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

и фрагмент где находится пользовательский интерфейс

```
public class ActivityHome extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {
GridView gridview;
AdapaterGridView gridviewAdapter;
ArrayList<GridViewItem> data = new ArrayList<GridViewItem>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

    gridview = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    data.add(new GridViewItem(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_product), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_product)));
    data.add(new GridViewItem(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_product2), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_product2)));
    data.add(new GridViewItem(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_product3), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_product3)));
    data.add(new GridViewItem(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_profile), getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_profile)));


    setDataAdapter();

    return v;
}

// Set the Data Adapter
private void setDataAdapter() {
    gridviewAdapter = new AdapaterGridView(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_list_item, data);
    gridview.setAdapter(gridviewAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> arg0, final View view, final int position, final long id) {
    if (position==0){
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityCategoryList1.class));
        getActivity().overridePendingTransition (R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
    }
    else if (position==1){
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityCategoryList2.class));
        getActivity().overridePendingTransition (R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
    }
    else if (position==2){
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityCategoryList3.class));
        getActivity().overridePendingTransition (R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
    }
    else if (position==3){
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityProfile.class));
        getActivity().overridePendingTransition (R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
    }
    else if (position==4){
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityInformation.class));
        getActivity().overridePendingTransition (R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
    }
    else if (position==5){
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityAbout.class));
        getActivity().overridePendingTransition (R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
    }
    else if (position==6){
        Intent sendInt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendInt.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.app_name));
        sendInt.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Магазин ShopApp\n\""+getString(R.string.app_name)+"\" \nhttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+getActivity().getPackageName());
        sendInt.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendInt, "Поделиться"));
    }
    else {
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityContactUs.class));
        getActivity().overridePendingTransition (R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
    }

}
```

Comment: Неужели попытки самостоятельного поиска каких-нибудь примеров не принесли никаких результатов?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927091/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5/927149#927149

Comment: Самостоятельный поиск принёс результаты , но почти все методы были реализованны через кнопку что в моём приложении нет ... и мне только и остаётся реализовать запрос  после входа в программу типа тоста ...